# Adding a white background to bootstrap navbar items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on making a personal site by playing around with bootstrap and I have a transparent navigation bar that looks like this:
[image]

Written like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Jon Snow - Knows    Nothing</a>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#about">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#work">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

This how the CSS is setup with different profiles for desktop and mobile sites:

```
 @media only screen
 and (min-width: 768px)  {

.navbar.navbar-default {
     padding:6px;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     border: none;
 }

 .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
 .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
     color: white;
 }
 .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
     border: none;
     box-shadow: none;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .navbar.navbar-default {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     border: none;
}

.icon-bar {
     background-color:#ffffff !important;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I am trying to add a highlight on hover and focus to my navbar item that is supposed to look like this:

[image]

I tried variations of this but no luck:

```
.nav li > a {
background-color:#000000;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also here is fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvp2z0ah/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work!

```
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
background-color:#000000;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
}
```